# Continuous Integration with multiple projects/languages/environments

Tags: build-process, continuous-integration, hudson

I want to setup a CI server (Hudson) here at my place and already set up a test environment where I can build some of our projects. Right now I'm doing .NET and Java, but there are some other languages coming up.

One project really needs a special environment (3rd party software, compiler, Linux as OS) and I wondered if someone can give me an advice about how to do it.

- Should I run another Hudson only for this project? I wanted to use Hudson on a spare Windows box, not on Linux. Building .NET on a Linux machine sounds complicated to me... ;-)
- Is there a way to have a "build-machine setup" where Hudson can delegate this project to another machine that is only there to build this single project?
- Or should I stop thinking about this problem at all and let the one project go on without continuous integration? (probably the simplest but worst option, because I want to run Checkstyle/StyleCop features in my Hudson to check for code conventions and such...)[

Answer (score 3):

check [distributed builds with hudson](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Distributed+builds) and [how to setup hudson for .NET projects](http://redsolo.blogspot.com/2008/04/guide-to-building-net-projects-using.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think the first link already gave me more insight.